# How does git ensure that commit SHA keys for identical operations/data are still unique?

Tags: git, uuid, sha

Q: What does git do to assure commit hashes are always unique even if they do the exact same operations with exactly the same contents. Does git simply use something like `uuidgen` to generate a unique id for the commit object or does it do something different based on a combination of a timestamp, your mac address, your wifi signals etc. per person?

If I create a file `foo` with `touch foo` and then run `shasum foo` it displays:

`da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709`.

No matter how often I run `shasum foo` or if I run it on a different computer it will always print `da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709` because, yep, it's the SHA1 representation of exactly the same contents. Empty contents in this case :)

However, if I do the following steps:

```
cd /some/where
mkdir demo
git init
touch foo
git add -A
git commit -m "adding foo"
```

..and remember the SHA key of the **commit** (e.g. `959c363ed4cf147725360532454bc258c964c744`).

Now, when I delete `demo` and repeat the exact same steps, still the **commit** SHA key will be different. And that is great and it's important to ensure *identity*.

Comment: Try it yourself with `git commit --date 'SOME DATE'`. You will get the same hash.

Comment: Nope, you won't :) I just tried it out using both times `git commit -m "adding foo" --date='Wed Jul 30 19:35:32 2014 -0700'`

Still, you get different SHA keys for your commit for your second attempt.

Comment: That is because `--date` only sets the author date, not the committer date. You can set both with the environment variables `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`; there is no command-line flag for committer date because you *really* shouldn't be setting it.

Comment: Awesome, I'll try that tomorrow. It might be the missing bit to make me believe it :) Rest assured that this question is purely because I'm obsessed with the details and does not have any practical purpose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What I would like to know though is, what exactly does git do to assure commit hashes are always unique even if they do the exact same operations with exactly the same contents.

Nothing.  If you create the same contents, you get the same SHA-1.

First, however, you need to realize that "same contents" of a commit means that—provided you don't get an accidental SHA-1 collision<sup>1</sup> or find a way to break SHA-1—you must create the same complete repository history leading up to and including the commit itself, including all the same trees, author-names, time-stamps, and so on.

This is because the contents of a commit *are* what you see if you run `git cat-file -p <sha-1>` on a commit (plus the tag-and-size field that says "this object is of type commit", so that there are no trivial ways to break things by creating a blob with the same contents as a previous commit).  Here's one as an example:

```
$ git cat-file -p 996b0fdbb4ff63bfd880b3901f054139c95611cf
tree e760f781f2c997fd1d26f2779ac00d42ca93f534
parent 6da748a7cebe3911448fabf9426f81c9df9ec54f
parent 740c281d21ef5b27f6f1b942a4f2fc20f51e8c7e
author Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1406140600 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1406140600 -0700

Sync with v2.0.3

* maint:
  Git 2.0.3
  .mailmap: combine Stefan Beller's emails
  git.1: switch homepage for stats
```

Note that this string includes the tree and its SHA-1, both of this commit's parent SHA-1s, the author and timestamp, the committer and timestamp, and the message.  If you change even a *single bit* of this—such as by trying to change the underlying tree, or using some different parent commit(s)—you will get a new, different SHA-1, rather than `996b0fdbb4ff63bfd880b3901f054139c95611cf`.

So the answer to this:

> So in theory if me and you do exactly the same steps at exactly the same time with exactly the same configured author, email etc, we would actually get the same commit SHA key?

is "yes".  However ... you must start with the same staging area (this is what will become the `tree`), and the same parent commits.  If you then configure your author, email, etc., exactly the same as the other guy, and both of you create a new commit at the same second (or using git's environment variables<sup>2</sup> to force the time stamps), you both get the same new commit.

Which is precisely what we want.  It doesn't matter if you create it, when you're named "me", or I create it, when I'm named "me", if all the rest of the contents are the same.  Because whoever creates it, the other "me" can clone it, and then we both have the same thing that way too.

(If I want to be sure that the "me" that creates something is not confused with the real me, I need to add something unique, that I know and the other me doesn't.  Of course, if I publish this thing somewhere, the other me know knows it.  But this is what signed, annotated tags are for.  They can contain a GPG signature.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The chances of an accidental hash collision (for any pair of objects; chances rise with more objects) are 1 out of 2<sup>160</sup>, which is ... very small. :-)  The rise is actually very rapid, so that by the time you have a million objects, it's about 1 out of 2<sup>121</sup>.  The formula I use here is:

1 - exp(((-(*n* * (*n*-1))) / (2 * *r*))

where *r* = 2<sup>160</sup> and *n* is the number of objects.  Without the subtraction from 1, the equation calculates the "safety margin", as it were: the chance that we *won't* have an accidental hash collision.  If we want to keep this number in the same range as the safety margin that a disk drive won't read back the wrong contents for a file—or at least, that disk-makers claim—we need to keep it around 10<sup>-18</sup>, which means we need to avoid putting more than about 1.7 quadrillion (1.7E15) objects in our git databases.

<sup>2</sup>There are many git environment variables that you can set to override various defaults.  The ones for the author and committer, including date and email, are:

- GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
- GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
- GIT_AUTHOR_DATE
- GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
- GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
- GIT_COMMITTER_DATE
- EMAIL

as described in the [git commit-tree documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit-tree.html).

Comment: That's an awesome answer. You should add the details about the environment variable provided by koaru 's comment though. I'll still need to try that out tomorrow when I'm on my machine. It's for learning purpose only.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't, but you will have to manually construct the commit to get the timestamps to line up. You can manually construct a whole valid repository identical to another, by editing the `.git/objects` files, but because newer commits contain the hashes of older commits this will of course have to be *exactly* identical.

Comment: Wait, does that mean it's really only the timestamps that make the difference? So in theory if me and you do exactly the same steps at exactly the same time with exactly the same configured *author*, *email*  etc, we would actually get the same commit SHA key?

Comment: I doubt even the timestamps are *required*. Everything you can get at with `git log` is in the commit, and gets hashed together. Git definitely doesn't grab junk from `/dev/urandom` and stick it in the commit, or some other thing. If you want to make your repository "unique" you'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: *"I doubt even the timestamps are required"*

But then why are the commit SHAs different for exactly the same operation/data with exactly the same commit information (author, email etc)? I think the timestamp is the only thing that differs if you repeat the steps laid out in the question on exactly the same machine twice.

Comment: @Christoph The timestamps are included normally, yes. Along with author information and all that. But I'm 99% certain you can make commits without them.

Answer (score 2):

The only things which are SHA-1'd to give the commit object its reference are what is shown by `git show <commit>`.

```
commit e6e53f5256c47b039ed19e95a073484dbb97cbf7
tree 543b9bebdc6bd5c4b22136034a95dd097a57d3dd
author Alex Balhatchet <kaoru@slackwise.net> 1406774132 -0700
committer Alex Balhatchet <kaoru@slackwise.net> 1406774132 -0700

    foo
```

That is:

1. The tree's id
2. The author name, email
3. The author commit timestamp
4. The committer name, email
5. The committer timestamp

The reason the examples with `--date` from other answers haven't worked is because you need to override both the committer timestamp and the author timestamp.

For example the following is completely repeatable:

```
alex@yuzu:~$ ( mkdir foo ; cd foo ; git init ; export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='Wed Jul 30 19:35:32 2014 -0700'; export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE; touch README; git add README; git commit README --message 'foo' --author 'Foo Bar <foo@example.com>'; git show HEAD --format=raw ; cd .. ; rm -rf foo ) 2>&1 | grep '^commit '
commit 7438e0a18888854650e6a53a9a5d823d6382de45
```

If you run it on your machine you should get exactly the same output.

**Update**

If you get different output it should at least be repeatable. For example I get different output for different versions of git; 1.7.10.4 reports a new empty README file as `0 files changed` whereas 1.9.1 reports it as `1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)` which changes the commit object's contents.

Answer (score 1):

This Gist from Carl Mäsak explains it better than I ever could:

https://gist.github.com/masak/2415865

```
alex@yuzu:~/foo$ git show HEAD
commit 7438e0a18888854650e6a53a9a5d823d6382de45
Author: Foo Bar <foo@example.com>
Date:   Wed Jul 30 19:35:32 2014 -0700

    foo

diff --git README README
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
```

Which is the SHA-1 checksum of "commit\0" followed by a character count (length) followed by `git cat-file commit HEAD`.

```
alex@yuzu:~/foo$ git cat-file commit HEAD
tree 543b9bebdc6bd5c4b22136034a95dd097a57d3dd
author Foo Bar <foo@example.com> 1406774132 -0700
committer Alex Balhatchet <kaoru@slackwise.net> 1406774132 -0700

foo
```

Put it all together and...

```
alex@yuzu:~/foo$ (printf "commit %s\0" $(git cat-file commit HEAD | wc -c); git cat-file commit HEAD) | sha1sum
7438e0a18888854650e6a53a9a5d823d6382de45  -
```

The sha1sum output matches the commit SHA-1!